# Css/js Include user uploaded font

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my app I allow users to upload custom fonts in various formats (like ttf, otf etc.).

These files are stored on a server and accessible via a simple GET request.

I built a select, which features these fonts, upon selection, the fonts of some elements should be changed to that font.

How should I go about changing the styles of the elements?
As far as I know there are 2 ways:

1. Loop through the custom font and include the font via link elements.
   This approach, however, is flawed, as I cannot reliably detect the font family name, so I could not set the font-family style, of the elements I want to style.
2. Incject css rules with @font-face.
   This approach would work, but it has definite security vulnerabilities, as I would have inject user generated css into the browser.

I use vuejs, so I could securely attach css to individual elements, but as far as I know @font-face does not work by redefining it at each element. Is there some attribute like font: url(src) I could use for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you say "user generated css" in option 2. It wouldn't be user generated css. You would generate this css yourself. Better than that, you are calling the font from your own API, so the only difference to a css from a user to another would be some parameters you can secure.

@font-face allows you to give whatever name you want to your font in the property `font-family`. You could create a pattern of names to your font families and give your elements these font names dynamically.

```js
  function changeFont() {
     // dynamic number. Create your own logic to generate this number
    const i = 123;

    // put your API path to the dinamic font file. I'm using a demo font
    const fontsource = "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotoslab/v11/BngbUXZYTXPIvIBgJJSb6s3BzlRRfKOFbvjoa4Omb2Rm.ttf";
    
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerHTML = `
      @font-face {
        font-family: customfont${i};
        src: url(${fontsource});
      }
    `;

    document.head.appendChild(style);

    const p = document.getElementById('text');

    p.style.fontFamily = 'customfont' + i;
  }
```

```html
<p id="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
<button onclick="changeFont()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer available. For others using this, please be only use completely save values for 'fontsource', as this approach is in danger of xss. But if one generates this link oneself, one should be save.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend anyone who's using uploaded fonts to do something similar to this, as it's more secure and does not risk any XSS injections as it avoid setting `innerHTML` to any content provided by the user.

```
function setFontFromFile(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (e) => {
    if (!e.target) return;
    if ("FontFace" in window) {
      const font = new FontFace("preview", `url(${e.target.result})`);

      font
        .load()
        .then((loadedFont) => {
          // delete the old preview font if it exists
          [...document.fonts.keys()].forEach((key) => {
            if (key.family === "preview") {
              document.fonts.delete(key);
            }
          });

          document.fonts.add(loadedFont);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Failed to load font: " + error);
        });

      const css = ".preview {font-family: preview;}";
      const style = document.createElement("style");
      style.innerText = css;
      style.setAttribute("id", "font-preview");
      // remove the existing style if it exists
      const existingStyle = document.getElementById("font-preview");
      if (existingStyle) {
        existingStyle.remove();
      }

      document.head.appendChild(style);
    }
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```